# タグの「別名」や「マージ」はどのような機能ですか？

Tags: サポート, タグ, よくある質問の案

タグの「別名」や「マージ」とはどのようなもので、どのような違いが有りますか？

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 5):

別名とマージは関連してはいるものの、まったく別の機能です。

- 別名は設定です。有効な間は常にユーザーの操作に干渉します。簡単に無効にできます。
- マージは処理です。データ（投稿）に対して一度切りの変更を加えます。簡単に元に戻す方法は有りません。

参照: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

---

### 別名

タグの別名は、ユーザーが別名を使用しても実名を使用したかのように扱うための設定です。設定方法などは、[「タグの別名の作成」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)を参照して下さい。

#### 別名の機能

別名を設定すると、ユーザーの操作に影響します。

- ユーザーが入力した別名を、操作の度に本名に置き換えて実行します。
- 既存のデータ（投稿）は変更されません。

影響するユーザーの操作には、

- 検索
- 投稿の作成や編集
- 関連するAPIの呼び出し

が有ります。例えば、別名で検索すると、本名のタグが付いた投稿が検索されます。新規投稿、あるいは編集された質問に別名のタグが付けられていると、代わりに本名でタグが付与されます。

#### 別名で生じる不都合

別名として設定されているタグ名は、入力しても本名に置き換えられるため、操作対象にできません。これは主に検索時に問題になります。別名のタグが付けられている投稿を、タグ指定で検索できません。

#### 別名の不都合の緩和策（検索時の例外）

上の不都合に対する緩和策として、検索時には例外が有ります。検索文字列がタグ指定のみの場合は、本名と別名の両方が検索対象になる（OR検索）機能です。

タグ検索の例:

- `[別名] 検索ワード`:
  本名タグが付いた投稿の中から、「検索ワード」を探します。別名タグが付いていても、本名が付いていなければ検索対象になりません。
- `[別名]`:
  本名か別名のタグが付いた投稿を探します（緩和策の対象）。
- `[別名] [他のタグ]`:
  本名か別名のタグが付いた投稿の中から、「他のタグ」も付いている投稿を探します（緩和策の対象）。

（これらの例は、別名部分を本名に変えて入力しても同じ結果になります）

#### 別名の不都合の解消（マージの必要性）

上で説明した不都合が許容されるのは一時的なことです。いずれ 解消しなければなりません。

そのためには、投稿に付いている別名タグを本名に変更します。これはデータ（投稿）の変更を伴ないますから、別名の設定とは大きく異なる、マージと呼ばれる処理です。

つまり、既存のタグを別名として設定した際には、後でマージが必要となります。

---

### マージ

タグのマージは、投稿に付いているタグを付け替える処理です。行なうにはモデレーター権限が必要です。

#### マージの動作

- 指定タグ名: 「ソースタグ」と「ターゲットタグ」を指定します。
- 処理対象: ソースタグが付けられている全ての質問です。
- 処理内容: 質問に付けられたソースタグを削除し、ターゲットタグを付与します。

#### マージと手作業によるタグの付け替え（編集）の違い

- マージは履歴に残らない: 対象の質問には、最初からターゲットタグが付与されていたかのように表示されます。
- マージではアクティブにならない: 対象の質問の更新日時が変更されず、アクティブ順で上位に表示されることがありません。

#### マージによるタグ名の変更

マージの際に指定するターゲットタグは、マージ以前に存在している必要は有りません。存在していないタグ名へのマージを行なうことができます。これは要するに、タグ名の変更です。

#### マージの取消し

基本的にはマージは取消しできないものです。ユーザーの手でマージ以前の状態に戻す方法は用意されていません。どの質問がマージされたのか、後から調べる方法も有りません。必要になった場合はStack Exchange社に依頼してみるしかありません。

---

### 用語の揺れ

ここで使用した用語には、下のような別の表現もあります。

- 別名 ／ 同義語 ／ シノニム ／ synonym
- 本名 ／ マスター ／ master
- マージ ／ merge ／ 統合 ／ 付け替え